# How to get data of the Task with await keyword?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

I just need in main code get FlowDocument...

I do like this but no success

```
this.flowDoc = engine.CreateFlowDocument(contentItems); // Can't compile
 public async Task<FlowDocument> CreateFlowDocument(ContentItems contentItems)
 {   return await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         try
         {
             var fd = new FlowDocument();
             foreach (var item in contentItems.Items)
             {
                 if (item.ContentType == ContentTypes.Header)
                 {
                     var paraHeader = new Paragraph();  
                     paraHeader.FontSize = 14;
                     paraHeader.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
                     paraHeader.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                     paraHeader.Inlines.Add(new Run(item.Data));
                     fd.Blocks.Add(paraHeader);
                 }
                 if (item.ContentType == ContentTypes.Paragraph)
                 {
                      var paragraph = new Paragraph();
                      paragraph.FontSize = 12;
                      paragraph.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
                      paragraph.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
                      paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(item.Data));
                      fd.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
                 }
             }                     
             return fd;
          }
          catch (Exception)     {                        }
          return new FlowDocument();
      }
                                 );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to await the task that you're returning from `CreateFlowDocument`:

```
 this.flowDoc = await engine.CreateFlowDocument(contentItems);
```

Of course, that means *that* code also have to be in an async function.

If you don't want it to be in an async method, you *could* use the `Result` property, but *please* only do so really carefully - that's a blocking call, and you can easily deadlock yourself.

Or you could attach a continuation with [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx).

Comment: Hmmm I have an exception: `Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.  
` Could you help with it please?

Comment: @Metropolitan: I very specifically said "Of course, that means that code also have to be in an async function." And the compiler error is pretty clear too. Which bit of those do you not understand? (Bear in mind that you've given us no indication of where that statement is... whether it's in the constructor, for example.)